# Google Spreadsheets Query( "where a matches '/[A-Z+]/' ") condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, regex

According to Google Query documentation:

> matches - A (preg) regular expression match. haystack matches needle
>   is true if the regular expression in needle matches haystack.
>   Examples: where country matches '.*ia' matches India and Nigeria, but
>   not Indiana. Note that this is not a global search, so where country
>   matches 'an' will not match 'Canada'.

I tried to use it in the formula `=query('Общий список'!A3:V;"select * where B matches '/[A-Z]+/' ")`, but the query returns empty output.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Where

Comment: Have you tried it without the forward slashes?

Comment: yep, same result.

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us?

Comment: I just realised that the sheet title is cyrillic. You may need to add an extra range for the upper case Russian(?) characters.

Answer (score 11):

> Note that this is not a global search...

This sentence explains what is going on: unlike the match in `regexmatch`, the `matches` clause of Query language requires the *entire* string to match the given regular expression. So, if you want to match strings where some part matches a regular expression `re`, the regular expression should be wrapped in `.*`:

```
select * where A matches '.*re.*'
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess, but OP may want something like this:

```
=query(A:A, "Select A where A matches '.*/[A-Z]+/.*' ")
```

to select from ColumnA only cells containing nothing but Latin alphabet upper case letters between two virgulas suspensiva (forward slashes) whether or not in the context of other characters.